# Android complex seekbar

Tags: android, user-interface, nine-patch

I need to create a seekbar that has custom background and custom thumb image. The problem is that background is kind of complex and i can't really create nice 9patch out of it.

Seekbar should have 3 values (0,1,2) and each value is represented by an image. Thumb should be centered around image of current value. Picture shows the seekbar with value "1" selected:

[image: seekbar]

Problems I had were:

1. to create a 9patch from background and keep edge and central image from moving / scaling.
2. create a thumb that will always be in right scale compared to images representing different values.

How can I do this?

### Edit

In short: I'm having troubles to make sure seekbar fills entire width of the screen (regardless of screen size), but again to make sure "ring" (thumb) will always fit perfectly around each "value" image.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand your problem, but you can create a bitmap xml to avoid resizing on your background pictures:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/mydrawable"
    android:tileMode="disabled" 
    android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

If you are having troubles with arranging the items/pictures, you can always play with a relative layout's diferent params.